# What is the best way to change the Status Bar color for all screens using nested navigation in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am currently using Expo and React Navigation to toggle between Dark Theme and Light Theme for my app. The only issue is that I’m not able to change the status bar color on iOS based on the theme.

I have a Tab Navigator nested inside of Drawer Navigator, but I’m having trouble figuring out how to change the status bar color on iOS when I toggle the theme for all screens in the nested navigation. This is what part of my drawer navigator looks like.

```
 <themeContext.Provider value={themeData}>
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme == 'Light' ? CustomDefaultTheme : CustomDarkTheme}>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          swipeEdgeWidth: 0,
          drawerActiveBackgroundColor: '#e8e4f0',
          drawerActiveTintColor: '#8a76b6',
          drawerInactiveBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
          drawerInactiveTintColor: '#bcbcc1',

        }}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use react-native's StatusBar methods to change it background or barStyle -

```
StatusBar.setBarStyle(theme == 'Light' ? 'dark-content' : 'light-content');
StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(theme == 'Light' ? '#fff' : '#000')
```

**call this above functions when you change theme.**

another way you can change it from root component if you want to change Status bar background for all screen then you can do like this -

```
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar } from 'react-native'

...
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
  <StatusBar
      backgroundColor={theme == 'Light' ? '#fff' : '#000'}
      barStyle={theme == 'Light' ? 'dark-content' : 'light-content'}
  />
  <ThemeContext.Provider value={themeData}>
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme == 'Light' ? CustomDefaultTheme : CustomDarkTheme}>
       <Drawer.Navigator
         screenOptions={{
           ...
         }}>
        ...
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `StatusBar` from `react-native`. I personally put it next to the `Navigator` (whatever you named it) in the `App.tsx`/`App.jsx`. Like example below:

```js
<>
  <StatusBar
  backgroundColor={
    theme == "Light"
      ? CustomDefaultTheme
      : CustomDarkTheme
  }
  barStyle={
    theme == "Light"
      ? CustomDefaultTheme
      : CustomDarkTheme
  }
  />
  <Navigation />
</>
```

You can adjust the `barStyle` and `backgroundColor` as you see fit.

For more details about `StatusBar` props, check [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#statusbarstyle)